# my xbox keep saying error 71 how can i fix this?

Tags: xbox-360

Help my Xbox wont load and keeps saying error 71 how do i fix this? iv tried taking the hardrive of and putting it back on, blowing into it i don't know what else to do.

Comment: I'm curious; when exactly does the error come up? When playing a game? As soon as the Xbox starts up? Please provide more detail.

Comment: The Xbox light turns red?

Answer (score 5):

I did a search and this came up, I hope it helps.

> **E71**: Dashboard Error - Error within Xam.xex: possibly a dashboard update error, Check below in the "Console Reset Codes" for
>   instructions. If that does not work there is no other solution and the
>   console must be sent back to MS for repair.
>
> **Console Reset Codes**
>
> Clear All Installed Game Updates and Console Cache
>
> - Go to the "system" blade
> - Select "memory"
> - Press Y on the HD symbol
> - Press X,X, Left Bumper, Right Bumper, X,X
> - A message will appear saying: "Do you want to perform maintenance on your Xbox 360 storage devices?"
> - Select Yes

**EDIT:**
After more research, I saw that another of the possible solutions to this problem can be solved with the hard drive:

> - Turn off the console
> - Disconnect all accessories (including video cables, network cable and any USB devices.)
> - Remove the hard drive
> - Reconnect all accessories
> - Connect the console (with the hard drive still disconnected)
>     If these steps do not resolve the problem, I think you need to request a repair.
>
> in Xbox Support

Comment: If you need a clarification from the asker that should be done in a comment on the question, not part of an answer.